# Implement swipe gesture on whole ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe-gesture

I need to implement a `swipe gesture` using `two finger touch input` on my `ListView` from right to left and vice-versa, but it should work exactly like an app named `Clean Master` who applied this under its "History" section (check the image) for going from Cache to Residual files (but using sinlgle touch input and i want to implement this using two finger touch input). If you've used this app, can you please tell me how to implement this. I've no idea being new to this concept. Please help me learn.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) what you need? Its a library called swipe listview.Its so easy to use and have customization options.

Comment: Thanks bro. But Your answer fulfills the second half of my work. This is one of the things i need to implement later. But before, just like this i need to swipe whole listview instead of a row inside it, taking two finger as a touch method.